# Object-to-Object/Value-to-Value storage and lookup

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

I have tuples of objects, like `(object, blob)`.

I can't derive a unique key from the object because it's a set of configurations from the users and there are a lot of configuration options. When configurations are submitted I must return a unique binary blob of, say, 10-20 Mb that can be generated by the backend.

However, I want to put a key-value store in front of blob generation so as to speed up my service's performance. Sort of like a cache but without a need for expiration, eviction, etc.

I'm free to decide on the storage at this point. I'm on GCP, so the blobs will most likely go into...drum rolling...blob storage. However, totally open about the rest of it.

What I was thinking is to take a hash table and pluck the `key` layer, to get something like this:

```
object1 -> hash1 -> [(object1, blobURL1)]
object2 -> hash2 -> [(object2, blobURL2), (object3, blobURL3)]
object3 -> hash2 -> points to the same slot as object2
```

I'm not concerned about search optimization inside the `linkedlist`(drawn as `array`), I'm not expecting to get a lot of collisions. It's just that if they occur, I should have a reliable way to get down to the right `blobUrl`. Comparing a couple of objects is not a big deal. Besides, there's no way to put it into a tree-like structure akin to [java 8-style optimized HashMap](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-performance).

Does my solution make sense or is it total gibberish? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What about generating hash of {hash, timestamp_of_request} which may contribute towards uniqueness in final hash value.

Comment: How can you make an appropriate hash if you can't make a unique key?

Comment: Well, @MattTimmermans, hash doesn't have to be unique. And hash function in general produces a constant-size, usually shorter value as compared to its input. I have an object with tons of fields. What's the problem with generating hashcode? I don't see any.